# No module named Sympy in jupyter

Tags: python, sympy

[image]

I downloaded and updated sympy, before that re - entered to jupyter

Comment: You want to use the newer magics commands when using pip or conda to install. See @SM1312's answer where you see `%pip install sympy`. You can learn more about the newer magic commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). You don't want to use the exclamation point with pip or conda. In fact, because automagics are usually on by default, use without any symbol usually defaults to the magic command.

Comment: And if @SM1313's good advice doesn't help you may want to try [force uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53066340/8508004) and then reinstall from a cell in your notebook,also using the magics. Try that only as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
%pip install --upgrade pip
%pip install sympy 
import sympy
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is

```
pip install --upgrade sympy
```

Then you could do

```
import sympy
```

For more info, visit this link: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pip-python-package-manager

If you want to upgrade pip, you could do the same thing:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed and import sympy in the anaconda jupyter environment with python 3.8.

```
!pip install sympy
import sympy
```

You can try quiting the notebook & navigator both and again re-open.

Comment: Please, don't advise folks to use `!pip`. That's outdated as the `%pip` and `%conda` magics have been added in the last few years to overcome environment issues that can be caused the use of the exclamation point before pip. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the current best practice with installs in the notebook via pip and conda.