# Issues with importing tensorflow python 3.7 on windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have issues with importing tensorflow on my computer.
After I received errors initially, I reinstalled Anaconda with the newest version Anaconda 5.3 for wihndows - python 3.7  . 
For the installation I used the following commands on cmd:

- `conda install tensorflow-gpu` - got an error because of different versions, and continued with the following:
- `conda create -n Tensorflow anaconda python=3.7` - installed some packages , as required
- `activate Tensorflow`
- `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` --> Got the following error : `tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Afterwards I tried to import it on jupyter notebook anyway and got error again:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Can anyone advise how can I solve it?

Comment: "got an error because of different versions" -- what is it? Please include the exact output.

Comment: This was the adviseI found here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240707/tensorflow-install-with-conda-conflict-unsatisfiableerror . I previously had python 3.6 on my computer, and decided to try the suggested solution  which worked actually.

Comment: Initial error I got was from type "UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict"

Comment: Please include the exact output into the question.

Comment: It's critical to know what requires what to decide what specifically to install next.

Comment: this is the full description of the error:UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - tensorflow-gpu
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: I don't think Tensorflow is supported on Python 3.7 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022

Comment: Add it to the question. It's unreadable in comment and I suspect there is at least one more line.

Answer (score 1):

just uninstall your python 3.7.xxxx versions,then install python 3.6.xx or lower version,now you can run pip install tensorflow successfully.
don't forget reset your ide's python path and reinstall other packages.